# Trying to override Mage_Core_Model_Domainpolicy

Tags: magento-1.9, overrides, module

I'm trying to override the model Mage_Core_Model_Domainpolicy. Everything should work by now, but, obviously, it doesn't. This is my config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <My_Module>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </My_Module>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <core>
                <rewrite>
                    <domainpolicy>My_Module_Model_Domainpolicy</domainpolicy>
                </rewrite>
            </core>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

My overriding class(app/code/local/My/Module/Model/Domainpolicy.php):

```
<?php

class My_Module_Model_Domainpolicy extends Mage_Core_Model_Domainpolicy {

    /**
     * Get frontend policy
     *
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getFrontendPolicy() {
        return null;
    }

}
```

And here my module xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <My_Module>
            <active>true</active>
            <codepool>local</codepool>
        </My_Module>
    </modules>
</config>
```

I've checked it a thousand times, but still NO clue what I'm doing wrong..

Comment: check compiler enable or not?Or Clear Cache

Comment: Compiler and cache is completely disabled, deleted cache, locks and tmp in the var folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your override might be correct. But look at this:

`app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml:158`

```
<security_domain_policy>
    <class>Mage_Core_Model_Domainpolicy</class>
    <method>addDomainPolicyHeader</method>
</security_domain_policy>
```

The class is hardcoded. So an override of the model will not work. The only way to override this class is to include the same class in the `app/code/local` folder.

Answer (score 6):

So as pointed out via another comment the class has been hardcoded in the event.

```
<events>
    <controller_action_predispatch>
        <observers>
            <security_domain_policy>
                <class>Mage_Core_Model_Domainpolicy</class>
                <method>addDomainPolicyHeader</method>
            </security_domain_policy>
        </observers>
    </controller_action_predispatch>
</events>
```

But this is not the end of the world what you can do is rewrite the config.xml here with your own config.xml.

Since the xml is Magento is merged you can do the following.

Add a `depends` node to Module xml so that the config.xml is loaded in the correct order.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <My_Module>
            <active>true</active>
            <codepool>local</codepool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Core/>
            </depends>
        </My_Module>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Now when you work on your config xml you can add the snippet.

```
<global>
        <events>
        <controller_action_predispatch>
            <observers>
                <security_domain_policy>
                    <class>Your_Class_Here</class>
                </security_domain_policy>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_predispatch>
    </events>
</global>
```

Now you can either hardcode the class name yourself or what I would do is use `core/domainpolicy` and then the normal config rewrite will work as expected.

Comment: +1, because this is what I want to add with @janw's answer. two questions. 1) still we cannto rewrite the method `Mage_Core_Model_Domainpolicy::addDomainPolicyHeader()` with this configuration, right ? 2)I can't see `method` node inside your code. Only class defined. In that case, which default method get called ?

Comment: @RajeevKTomy sure you can rewrite the method it is the same as a normal rewrite simply extend the base class and you can do what you like. Also you do not need the method node as you are not changing the method being called.

Comment: I think I didnt get the first point. This is my understanding on events. "Magento will execute the method specified in the observer class in the loading order of modules once a specific event is dispatched." If that is the case, `Mage_Core_Model_Domainpolicy::addDomainPolicyHeader()` will get executed then it will execute `My_Module_Model_Observer::addDomainPolicyHeader()`. My point is first method is also executing rather than skipping it ! Am I right ?

Comment: if we make `Mage_Core` module depend on our module, then first priviledge for our module. This way we will get full access to do anything over the class `Mage_Core_Model_Domainpolicy`. What would you think about that ?

Answer (score 0):

you have to define your model `classname` as well with global tag

```
<global>
    <models>
        <my_module>
            <class>My_Module_Model</class>
        </my_module>

        <core>
            <rewrite>
                <domainpolicy>My_Module_Model_Domainpolicy</domainpolicy>
            </rewrite>
        </core>
    </models>
</global>
```

hope this will work for you

Comment: He means that you forgot model class declaration in your config         <my_module><class>My_Module_Model</class></my_module>

Comment: Oh that's what I did:
`<my_module><class>My_Module_Model_Domainpolicy</class></my_module>`

Comment: It didn't work, unfortunately! :/

Comment: try to check with `get_class` function to see which class is used currently in your file

Comment: This is what I have at the moment: https://gist.github.com/Desmaster/40327a4c48be90e242c1

Answer (score 0):

Create new file in magento root with the following code and show us the result

```
<?php

require_once("app/Mage.php");
umask(0);
Mage::app();

error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
Mage::init();

$object = Mage::getModel('core/domainpolicy');
$rewrite = (string)Mage::getConfig()->getNode()->global->models->core->rewrite->domainpolicy;
$active = (string)Mage::getConfig()->getNode()->modules->Zhartaunik_Test->active;

echo "Object: " . get_class($object) . "<br />";
echo "Rewrite: " . $rewrite . "<br />";
echo "Is Active: " . (string)$active  . "<br />";
```

Comment: That gives back `Mage_Core_Model_Domainpolicy` without errors/warnings/notices.

Comment: have you cleaned the cache?

Comment: Yes, I removed cache/, locks/ and tmp/ from the var/ directory.

Comment: Object returns `Mage_Core_Model_Domainpolicy`, Rewrite returns nothing and Is Active returns `true`.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B63my1juIqesZFloVmVzZ3NYeUU/view?usp=sharing make a backup of your module before upload. You can replace some files

Comment: Did you install this? Does it work?

Comment: I will get back to this monday! Sorry for the delay

Comment: In my case any of these solutions worked, neither the module provided by @zhartaunik